# How do I build a node native module with rpath in AWS Lambda?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, node-gyp

I'm trying to use [`node-phash`](https://github.com/aaronm67/node-phash) in an `aws lambda` function, but coming-up short.

I've found instructions for the `node-canvas` library [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33929870/node-canvas-build-for-aws-lambda) and on github, but still having some trouble.

Steps I've taken:

1. on an Amazon Linux ec2 instance, I've cloned the `node-phash` repo
2. I set an env var to use an `rpath`, as the `node-canvas` walkthrough instructed:

   `export LDFLAGS=-Wl,-rpath=/var/task/`
3. I determined the shared deps:

   ```
   $ readelf -d pHashBinding.node | grep NEEDED
     0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library:      [libstdc++.so.6]
     0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libm.so.6]
     0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libgcc_s.so.1]
     0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libpthread.so.0]
     0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
   ```
4. I then copied and downloaded the listed files to include in my `zip` for `lambda`
5. I ran `npm install`, which went ostensibly fine
6. I confirmed that the `.node` would look at the `aws lambda` root for its deps:

   ```
    $ objdump -p build/Release/pHashBinding.node | grep RPATH
       RPATH                /var/task/
   ```
7. I then downloaded the `build/Release` folder and overwrote my project's `node_modules/phash/build/Release` with the folder from the Amazon Linux environment
8. I zipped my project for upload to `Lambda`, including the 5 `*.o` files from step 3 into the root of the zip, so they'd be unzipped at `/var/task/` in `Lambda`

Unfortunately, after all that, I still get the same errors I did before:

```
"errorMessage": "/usr/local/lib64/node-v4.3.x/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /var/task/node_modules/node-phash/build/Release/pHashBinding.node)",
  "errorType": "Error",
  "stackTrace": [
    "Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:434:18)",
    "Module.load (module.js:343:32)",
    "Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)",
    "Module.require (module.js:353:17)",
    "require (internal/module.js:12:17)",
    "Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/node-phash/lib/phash.js:23:13)",
    "Module._compile (module.js:409:26)",
    "Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)",
    "Module.load (module.js:343:32)"
  ]
}
```

`libstdc++.so.6` is in the root of my `zip`.  So, how do I get `pHashBinding.node` to reference the correct directory when looking for dependencies?

Comment: op here--if anyone finds themselves in a similar predicament, I eventually just resorted to using a [python image hashing library](https://github.com/JohannesBuchner/imagehash) for this function. I'm not great at Python, but I was able to get a functional microservice setup in short order (and most of the native dependencies for python are widely avail. as prebuilt on aws linux)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an older question but I was struggling with this and managed to find a solution that might work for you as well.

This solution comes from a GitHub discussion here https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/6443#issuecomment-270558452

Basically you should use Docker to install your packages when you are ready to deploy to AWS Lambda.

1. Delete the `node_modules` folder inside your project.
2. Open terminal and `cd` into your project folder.
3. Run this command `docker run --rm -it -v "$PWD":/worker -w /worker node:4.2 npm i --production --silent`

Afterwards you should see a `node_modules` folder in your project, this can now be zipped up and uploaded to AWS Lambda.

This should work for any dependencies that require native code when `npm install` is run.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Docker is not needed (only for this specifc scenario) if you're already using Linux.